# VBA - Resizing a picture in excel

Tags: excel, vba, image, userform, transfer

The code bellow paste the picture from my form into an activecell. But, how can I Resize the picture before past into excel?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 TransferToSheet Me.Image1, Plan2, 350
End Sub

Private Sub TransferToSheet(picControl, sht As Worksheet, picWidth As Long)
Const TemporaryFolder = 2
Dim fso, p

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
p = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder).Path & "\" & fso.gettempname
SavePicture picControl.Picture, p

With picControl.Picture.Insert(p)
.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
.Width = picWidth
End With
   
fso.deletefile p
Unload Me
```

End Sub

Comment: Are you resizing by percentage or fixed width/height

Comment: I'm trying by fixed width/height.

Comment: Also what is SavePicture? Is that your own routine or a built-in VBA function? If it's yours, please include code

Comment: SavePicture it's a VBA routine.

Comment: What line does that error happen on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - I modified previous answer to handle fact that picture is actually a Shape - and you resize by using ShapeRange of the image.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TransferToSheet Image1, Worksheets("Sheet1"), 350
End Sub


Private Sub TransferToSheet(picControl, sht As Worksheet, picWidth As Long)
    Const TemporaryFolder = 2
    Dim fso, p

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    p = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder).Path & "\" & fso.gettempname
    SavePicture picControl.Picture, p ' save to temp file
        
    ' Insert temp file inot new image
    With sht.Pictures.Insert(p)
        ' Resize
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = picWidth
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Delete Temp File
    fso.DeleteFile p
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I  didn't understand what you say, because I replaced my code...but, it's not working.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and show your what you tried - and describe "not working"  Try putting that line back in (see my edited answer - SavePicture picControl.Picture, p

Comment: `Private Sub TransferToSheet(picControl, sht As Worksheet, picWidth As Long)
    Const TemporaryFolder = 2
    Dim fso, p
    Set picWidth = 50
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    p = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder).Path & "\" & fso.gettempname
    SavePicture picControl.Picture, p
    
    With picControl.Picture.Insert(p)
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    .Width = picWidth
    End With
       
    fso.deletefile p
    Unload Me
End Sub`

Comment: Edit your question - no one can read it in the comments

Comment: Okay, the edition is done.

Comment: You're not passing the width - see my example

Comment: Actually, I did. But, it gives me an error 438, "With picControl.Picture.Insert(p)".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237805/discussion-between-pedro-and-dbmitch).

Comment: I modified code and and tested from a Userform. It inserts and resizes a userform picture to the selected cell in Sheet1 - change Sheet Name to match yours.